# is there a way to exclude a package from iOS in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, podfile

I am making use of the package "sms_maintained" which is only available for Android.

However, the project needs an iOS version and what I am doing currently is to remove the package when developing for iOS.

How can I keep the package in the pubspec.yaml file but disable iOS from checking into the package? The goal is to have a uniform codebase.

I have tried to exclude the package in the Podfile using

```
skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/","sms_maintained"]
```

which skips the package but during build a reference is made to GeneratedPluginRegistrant which is auto generated.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm just wondering what's the problem if the package is not excluded ? You should check the iOS implementation, I'm pretty sure it will return a default response.

Comment: How do you expect Flutter to not to register the plugin? You are literally using it on Android.

Comment: yeah @danypata just like @Firat is insinuating, it throws this during build  "No podspec found for `sms_maintained`"

Answer (score 1):

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors

check this out, you can setup different flavours according to different environment of release and development

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, flavors are really cool but if I change the packages to suit the platform during build,  it will still cause build issues as references to the package in the project will point to no file. What I would like is to keep the package there but tell flutter to not register it

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution to the problem, the sms_maintained package indeed has a podspec file named sms.podspec in the ios/.symlinks/plugins which should be renamed to sms_maintained.podspec.

Also open the file and rename sms in the s.name key to sms_maintained

Rerun the app

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain this a little bit more. As I as reader cannot know what do you mean by "sms", "open the file" etc