# Huawei_analytics only for android exclude ios

Tags: ios, flutter, huawei-developers, podfile

My flutter project I published on PlayMarket, Huawei AppGallery & AppStore.

in my pubspec.yaml I added

```
huawei_push: ^6.3.0+304
huawei_analytics: ^6.5.0+300
```

and on android `build.gradle` I wrote extra script which builds different depends on `--dart-define=BUILD_TYPE=HUAWEI` or other.

But on ios it tries to use both and crushes with exception. On ios I need only Firebase.
Exception:

```
'NSGenericException', reason: 'agconnect-services.plist Not Found.'
```

How to exclude **HiAnalytics** and **HMFoundation** Pods?

I think on Podfile I need any thing like this:

```
flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
// exclude HiAnalytics
```

Comment: shouldn't you fix the crash instead of avoiding it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a way to exclude a package from iOS in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637307/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-a-package-from-ios-in-flutter)

Comment: @Raptor I need only one (Firebase) on ios side. It crushes with message: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'agconnect-services.plist Not Found.'`